# What does use of TrieNode data structure in TrieNode class mean?

Tags: python, oop, trie

I saw the following piece of code in many trie questions where the class is used inside itself as a defaultdict data structure. I understand that it means that children is dictionary of TrieNode. However, I do not understand the base case (the very last child). There is no None or empty definition for it. I was wondering if someone can explain it.

```
class TrieNode():
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = collections.defaultdict(TrieNode)
        self.isWord = False
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a recursive data structure, commonly used for trees. Makes sense for tries too, I guess.

In this case, if `self.children` is empty (i.e. `len(self.children) == 0`), the data structure bottoms out. That's when you have reached the "end" of the trie. Well, really, *one* end of it.

Comment: Greg Ward, How do you define "empty"? If it was a collections.defaultdict(list). I would say [], but not sure what to say in the recursive data structure case.

Answer (score 1):

Trie is usually used for searching a given string from a set of strings dynamically. Each string will consist of a finite no of possible characters which is stored in self.children. So each preceding character is connected to its succeeding characters through self.children and each character is a key and each value is a TrieNode object.

Consider words {"can", "cancel"}. The trie constructed for these words will be:
c-a-n-c-e-l. Since both words have same prefix, they have the same sequence of characters. The isWord flag is used for checking if a character is the end of a word found in our set so the isWord flag of characters n and l will be true. Thus n and all its preceding characters form a word in our set

If a character is the last character of a word and no other words have the same prefix (base case), it will have no children so self.children will be an empty dictionary == {}.